# Converting a table to a different form

Tags: sql, database-normalization

Can you help me how to convert the table A to table B?

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. @soorapadman Please don't inline linked images that should be text, please tell the poster to use text.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Moving between data values & column names is called pivoting.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization. PS Please dont dump requirements, show research & parts you can do.

Answer (score 3):

One approach which should work on most SQL databases uses a series of unions:

```
SELECT BRAND, 'MODEL A' AS TYPE, MODELA AS TOTAL
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT BRAND, 'MODEL B', MODELB FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT BRAND, 'MODEL C', MODELC FROM yourTable
ORDER BY BRAND, TYPE;
```

By the way, the operation you are trying to do is usually called "unpivot," and certain databases, such as Oracle and SQL Server, support a formal `UNPIVOT` operator.